# Python - Flask method call inside if statement

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask. I am trying to call a method defined in the python file. The method is setup properly in the python file (tested). Now in the HTML file I want to call this method within an if statement. So in Java it would be something like:

```
if (allowAccess() == 1){...}
```

I have tried the following:

```
{% if {{ allowAccess() }} == 1 %}

            <p>test message</p>

{% endif %}
```

But i get the error:

> expected token : got }

Comment: Can you try to with `{% if allowAccess()  == 1 %}` ?

Comment: @RajaSimon I thought I tried this earlier, anyway I tried it again and it worked thanks. If you put it as answer ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put {{ inside the conditional templates statement... So answering the question would be...

```
{% if allowAccess() == 1 %}
```